# Differential equation using substitution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How would I use the substitution $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}$ to solve the diffy eq $\frac{dy}{dx} = ay-by^3$, where a and b are constants?

I thought about applying chain rule 
$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dy}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v=f(x)$ then 
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{dx}v^{-1/2} = -\dfrac{1}{2}v^{-3/2}\dfrac{dv}{dx}
$$
Then thinsgs you should try is putting in the substitution for $y$ on the right hand side?

Another thing that would be great so you can see where this arises is to do the same trick for the general case for this particular family of Bernoulli ODES
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = ay + by^n
$$
and use a substitution of $y=v^{m}$ for example? and try find the condition on m in terms of n.